# transform rows into columns in a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Supose I would like to store a table with 440 rows and 138,672 columns, as SQL limit is 1024 columns I would like to transform rows into columns, I mean to convert the
440 rows and 138,672 columns to 138,672 rows and 440 columns.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's called "pivoting" -- see the pivot tag info page for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pivot/info

Comment: And What are the steps in SQL Server 2008?. Is there a script or stored proc to do this?

Comment: There are 535 questions tagged as pivot; there are numerous examples already on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of the data is as follows....

> Each attribute describes the measurement of the occupancy rate
>   (between 0 and 1) of a captor location as recorded by a measuring
>   station, at a given timestamp in time during the day.
>        The ID of each station is given in the stations_list text file.
>
> For more information on the location (GPS, Highway, Direction) of each
>   station please refer to the PEMS website.
>
> There are 963 (stations) x 144 (timestamps) = 138,672 attributes for
>   each record.

**This is perfect for normalision.**

You can have a stations table and a measurements table.  Two nice long thin tables.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server limit is actually 30000 columns, see [Sparse Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx).

But creating a query that returns 30k columns (not to mention +138k) will be basically uncontrollable, the sheer size of the metadata on each query result would halt the client to a crawl. One simply does not design databases like that. Go back to the drawing board, when you reach 10 columns stop and think, when you reach 100 column erase the board and start anew.

And read this: [Best Practices for Semantic Data Modeling for Performance and Scalability](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2008/09/03/best-practices-for-semantic-data-modeling-for-performance-and-scalability.aspx).

Comment: Well the data is like that  440 rows and 138,672 columns, I am planning to use data from UCI http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/PEMS-SF How to overcome this situation?

Comment: Read the link at the end of my post.

Comment: +1 just for saying this, "Go back to the drawing board, when you reach 10 columns stop and think, when you reach 100 column erase the board and start anew".  Great whitepaper too.